# Odata web service without using Entity Framework

Tags: odata

I want to write an OData REST web service.

However I don't want to use Entity Framework for accessing my SQL data.

Is there a library to parse the OData parameters and pass it to my custom written stored procedures?

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: no i haven't. i am looking for a library/code to translate odata query to sql query

Comment: Did you come across any means by which you were able to translate the OData Query to other means so that we can query the Non-EF based data?